# How to share/access partitions from ubuntu VMware?

Tags: partitioning, virtualization, vmware

I am a beginner at Ubuntu. Here is my problem.

I have Ubuntu installed on my external HDD and I am running XP through VMware on Ubuntu, because my internal disk is dead at the moment. External HDD have ext4 (37GB) and 2 NTFS partitions (36GB and 220GB).

How can I access that 220GB (or 36GB) NTFS partitions from VMware XP? I already tried searching for similar posts but with no luck.

Comment: This a long process and I had a lot of issues doing it. Don't remember the exact page anymore, but try looking for making a virtual disk from a physical disk. Once you complete the process of linking a virtual disk to a physical disk you can mount it in the same virtual machine as a second drive. I was attempting to access a physical drive to run the os in virtual box and it ran horribly and had very slow access. Not worth it unless 100% necessary.

Comment: Did you install VMWare Tools?

Comment: @shonjones I know that is long, process but i really need Windows with access to disk. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Mitch I have installed VMWare Tools rite now. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Open VMWare, and right click on the VM, and click on settings
[image]

Then click on options --> Shared folders
[image]
Then click on Always enable --> Add
[image]
Then Browse to the folder of your choice, click Next, and follow the on screen instructions.
[image]